# Preventing memory leaks with object wrappers

Tags: swift, oop, modeling

I have a modeling problem.

I have a wrapper class to control mutations to the wrapped object:

```
/// A wrapper that enables controlled mutations to the wrapped object and the ability to respond to
/// those mutations.
open class Mutating<T: Codable>: Deinitializing {
    
    
    //
    //
    //    MARK: - Stored Properties
    //    ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    //    ||||||||        Stored Properties        |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    //    ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    //
    //
    //
    
    /// The wrapped object.
    fileprivate var value: T
    
    /// Closures ran after every mutation.
    private var sideEffects: [SideEffect]
    
    
    //
    //
    //    MARK: - Computed Properties
    //    ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    //    ||||||||        Computed Properties        |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    //    ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    //
    //
    //
    
    /// A copy of the wrapped object.
    ///
    /// Not providing access to the actual wrapped value prevents uncontrolled mutations to it.
    public var copy: T { return try! JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: JSONEncoder().encode([self.value]))[0] }
    
    
    //
    //
    //    MARK: - Instance Methods
    //    ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    //    ||||||||        Instance Methods        ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    //    ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    //
    //
    //
    
    /// Provides the opportunity to access and mutate the wrapped object.
    ///
    /// After every mutation, all side effects are executed.
    ///
    /// - Parameter mutation: The closure which is given access to the wrapped object.
    /// - Throws: Rethrows any errors thrown by the passed closure.
    public func mutate(_ mutation: (inout T) throws -> ()) rethrows {
        let old=self.copy
        try mutation(&self.value)
        self.causeSideEffects(old)
    }

    /// Appends a side effect.
    ///
    /// - Parameter sideEffect: A closure that is executed after every mutation with copies of the post- and pre-mutation values,
    ///                         in that order.
    public func add(sideEffect: @escaping (T,T) -> ()) {
        self.sideEffects.append(SideEffect(sideEffect))
    }
    
    /// Executes all side effects.
    ///
    /// - Parameter old: A copy of the pre-mutation value.
    private func causeSideEffects(_ old: T) {
        self.sideEffects.forEach { $0.closure(self.copy, old) }
    }
    
    
    //
    //
    //    MARK: - Initializers
    //    ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    //    ||||||||        Initializers        ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    //    ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    //
    //
    //
    
    public init(_ value: T) {
        self.value=value
        self.sideEffects=[]
    }
}
```

Early on with this class I faced a problem where I wanted to pass the object around while restricting the ability to mutate the object to its owner. So I created these:

```
public extension Mutating {

    /// An `Accessor` to self.
    public var accessor: Accessor { return Accessor(value: self) }

    /// A wrapper for a `Mutating` object to enable passing around access to it without providing
    /// the means to mutate it.
    public struct Accessor {
        
        /// The wrapped object.
        fileprivate let value: Mutating<T>
        
        
        //
        //
        //    MARK: - Wrapped API
        //    ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
        //    ||||||||        Wrapped API        |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
        //    ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
        //
        //
        //
        
        public var copy: T { return self.value.copy }
        public func add(sideEffect: @escaping (T,T) -> ()) { self.value.add(sideEffect: sideEffect) }
    }
}
```

Now what I ultimately want is to be able to treat an `Accessor` like the `Mutating` object it's providing access to. In an ideal world, they would both simply be the same object. An `Accessor` would just be a transparent wrapper over a `Mutating` object that prevents using `mutate(_:)`. This way, when it comes to ARC and reference counting I would be able to treat them both like they're the same thing — just different 'views' into a single object. I would be able to capture an `Accessor` weakly in closures and they would not prevent the wrapped `Mutating` object from being deallocated.

But unfortunately we don't live in that world at the moment, and if I capture an `Accessor` in a closure it is going to continue to strongly hold onto the `Mutating` object it is wrapping and I want to be able to capture the `Accessors` without inadvertently strongly capturing the underlying `Mutating` object.

Some things I've considered:

1. Creating some artificial inheritance relationship between the two — Unfortunately, then you could just cast an `Accessor` to a `Mutating` and get back that mutation functionality.
2. Weakly capturing the `Mutating` object in `Accessor` — Don't want to deal with optionals when the data is architecturally non-optional.
3. 2), but using `unowned` — No compiler time safety.

Comment: Maybe I didn't read very carefully, but isn't this sort of reinventing the wheel? I mean, the only truly mutable things are class instances, because everything else is passed as a copy; and Cocoa already has a well established pattern of class clusters, e.g. NSString / NSMutableString, NSArray / NSMutableArray, and so on, where you _vend_ the immutable and _copy_ the incoming value to the immutable, so that only the owner can access mutability.

Comment: @matt Not sure I understand your point completely, but one thing to note is that what I need is the vended piece of data to still be able to change, the change just cannot be made using the vended data — it can only be mutated from the source. We're talking about property observers, so I don't see how immutability plays a role here.

Comment: Well, again, if the vended data is a struct or an enum, it is passed by value, which is a copy. So the only case of concern is a class, which is passed by reference. So if you don't want _your_ instance to change just because someone else receives the vended object and changes it, _you_ pass a copy. — As I say, I might be missing the whole point.

Comment: @matt Yes, you are because if the whole point is to enable others access without mutation then passing a copy doesn't accomplish that. Sure they can access what the instance's data was at the time of copying, and sure they can't mutate this new immutable instance, but you've now vended some entirely new instance. A reference type has identity and the objects that require access but not mutation are relying on that unique identity.

Comment: They don't necessarily need the exact same instance, but however it's accomplished the vended data needs to be linked to the original `Mutating` instance such that mutations to the original are reflected in the vended data. In other words, the vended data *cannot be static*. And you'll find in this scenario the original data is a `Mutating` instance which is a `class` type. It's in the question.

Comment: Ok that’s the opposite of what I thought you wanted to do. So what you are describing now is just what a class instance does by default?

Comment: @matt No, you cannot grant/restrict access to a class member to specific instances. You can only use the limited number of access modifiers swift provides and perhaps attributes like `@available`. None of these alone will enable you to instantiate a `Mutating` instance, and then pass it around to other instance with its  `mutate(_:)` method inaccessible. If it's accessible to the object that instantiated it, it will be to whoever its passed to.